# How could I implement my library/game to run in a browser plugin?

Tags: sfml, browser, plugin

I usually code cross-platform, to build as native code for Mac Linux and Windows,
but I clearly see the value in being able to display my game in a browser.

Could you guide me in doing such a task? How could i have something like Unity Web Player?
Cross-browser is preferable, but Chrome would already be great  :)

I use technologies such as SFML, libRocket, Box2D and more.. If that is pertinent to the question!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the standard interface for browser plugins is [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) (Netscape Plugin API).  More recently, there's been a move towards [Pepper](http://code.google.com/p/ppapi/).  However, I would **strongly** discourage you from making a browser plugins.  Users hate it and it's generally *really* suspicious since plugins let you do more or less anything with a user's computer.

If you're really set on using native code, your best bet is probably [Google Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) (NaCL).  This lets you run native code at near native speeds within a sandboxed environment.  It's already been used to port Bastion to the Chrome web store thingy.  This also has the advantage over a normal plugin of being at least somewhat cross-platform.  It requires a specialised compiler toolchain which (from memory) currently uses GCC/G++.  Mono has also been ported to NaCL, so you can run C#, F#, Java (via IKVM), etc.

That said, it still requires your users to install a plugin if they aren't using a very recent version of Chrome, but at least they only need to trust Google as opposed to some random developer they've never heard of before.

Comment: If you strongly discourage that, i will certaintly take it into account. I enjoyed the  NaCL solution, and i will leave it in the table for the future. For now, i think i will drag myself into mobile phones more than browsers. Why try to copy flash if i could have just started with it? If i am using C++, it must be for a reason! Thanks for the answer! :)